# Cannot convert lambda expression to type bool

Tags: c#, types, lambda, boolean

Cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it is not a delegate type.

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int totalpoints;
        Int32 realpoints;
        lelpoints = 0;
        totalpoints = Convert.ToInt32(dPts.Text);
        totalpoints = totalpoints + 1;
        totalpoints = realpoints;
        dPts.Text = totalpoints.ToString();

    }


    protected void buyBG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] rbg = new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" };


        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 3);
        string currentbg = rbg[randomNumber];

        if (realpoints => 10 ){}
```

This is the issue I'm experiencing with the code I've provided above. The issue is showed at the If statement at the bottom.

Edit: Changing `=>` to `>=` definitely resolved that issue but now it reports an error "the name realpoints does not exist in the current context". Thank you

Comment: Switch the `=` and `>`. `=>` makes a lambda, `>=` is the "greater-than-or-equals" operator. Voting to close as off-topic due to simple typographical error.

Comment: As of your edit: yeah, I saw that one coming too. Define `realpoints` outside of methods to fix the error. If you have further problems, ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you, in case further issues appear I shall ask a new question. My apologies for the hassle, this question has been concluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not `=>`, but `>=`.

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: You should vote to close rather than answer.

Comment: @Jashaszun: there is no reason for closing this, unless there is a dupplicate. Simple question?  Yes.  Reasonable in any case ? Yes.

Comment: Are you serious? As a 45.5k rep user, you should know the close reasons by now. One of them is "Off-topic due to a simple typographical error", which is exactly what this question is.

Comment: @Jashaszun: this is not a "typografic error". this is lack of knowledge of the language

Comment: The fact that he asked the question means he didn't understand the difference between `=>` and `>=`, its bigger than just a simple typo, i'm sure he learned a lot about what a lambda expression is.

Answer (score 1):

`=>` is a *lambda* operator is not the same as the greater than or equal to operator `>=`

Answer (score 0):

you can read => (lambda sign) as "goes to". Means you are passing a parameter to a delegate body. In your case realpoints => 10 mean realpoints  is parameter and 10 is a body and this body is not bool type (10 is not bool).

For example you have a list of integer like:
 List intList = new  List {10, 14,5,17};

you want to find the first integer in the list which is  greater than 10 then you can use lambda expression something like
int numberFound =  intList.Find(x => x > 10 );

Thanks,
Sukh